# Java: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.apache.fontbox.cmap.CMapParser.<init>(boolean)

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, nosuchmethoderror

I am trying to read a PDF document with Java. I am new to this and also new to configuring dependencies w/ intelliJ. The full error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.apache.fontbox.cmap.CMapParser.<init>(boolean)'
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.CMapManager.parseCMap(CMapManager.java:74)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont.readCMap(PDFont.java:213)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont.loadUnicodeCmap(PDFont.java:147)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont.<init>(PDFont.java:115)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont.<init>(PDSimpleFont.java:74)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont.<init>(PDTrueTypeFont.java:185)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFontFactory.createFont(PDFontFactory.java:89)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDResources.getFont(PDResources.java:146)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.text.SetFontAndSize.process(SetFontAndSize.java:66)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processOperator(PDFStreamEngine.java:933)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processStreamOperators(PDFStreamEngine.java:515)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:489)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processPage(PDFStreamEngine.java:156)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.text.LegacyPDFStreamEngine.processPage(LegacyPDFStreamEngine.java:144)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper.processPage(PDFTextStripper.java:394)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper.processPages(PDFTextStripper.java:322)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper.writeText(PDFTextStripper.java:269)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper.getText(PDFTextStripper.java:233)
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:18)
```

My present code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File("src/dummy.pdf"));
    if(!document.isEncrypted()){
        PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
        String text = stripper.getText(document);
        System.out.println("Text:"+text);
    }
    document.close();
}
```

Here are the jars I have installed:

[image]

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Here is a link to the pdf I am trying to read. Note that it is in Japanese font:

https://www.soumu.go.jp/main_content/000731590.pdf

Comment: Please quote error messages accurately and completely.

Comment: You need to use the same version for pdfbox and fontbox (2.0.23). Jempbox isn't needed for text extraction. Be sure to delete old versions when testing again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tilman Hausherr was correct. The difference in versions between PDFBox and Fontbox was the error.